# 98 Jeep Wrangler Engine coolant leak in front of engine

Tags: jeep, coolant-leak, wrangler

I just got my jeep back from the mechanics i had to replace my power steering pump and today i noticed a green liquid leaking from under my jeep i checked the fluid its 100% engine coolant i checked around my entire reservoir no leak anywhere around it all hoses in place and tight. its more by my engine block i'm so scared when they were fixing my power steering pump they somehow cracked my radiator i just paid 490 some to replace my pump so i have no clue what to do can someone please tell me what it could be cause i cannot afford to go back to the mechanics

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine is in your Jeep (4-cyl or 6-cyl)?

Comment: OP if the water pump was *just* replaced, it's possible the techs, for whatever reason, didn't get a good seal at the gasket. What do you mean by "just" replaced: Two days? Two Months? There may be a warranty for the work.